# Calculating cumulative returns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have calculated the daily returns from some market data and am trying to add each of those returns in an accumulation column (cum_rets). Here's a sample of the data:

```
    timestamp   dash_cap    litecoin_cap    dogecoin_cap    nxt_cap Total_MC    Dal_rets
0   2014-02-14  702537  410011811   80883283    61942277    553539908   NaN
1   2014-02-15  1054625 413848776   73684156    59127182    547714739   -1.052349
2   2014-02-17  1882753 407014106   70512004    59753481    539162344   -1.561469
3   2014-02-18  3766068 398556278   69890414    60219880    532432640   -1.248178
4   2014-02-19  3038521 404855950   71588924    59870181    539353576   1.299871
```

I don't understand why, when I use this code:

```
merged['cum_rets'] = 0
merged['cum_rets'] = merged['cum_rets'].shift(1) + merged.Dal_rets
merged
```

it returns

```
    timestamp   dash_cap    litecoin_cap    dogecoin_cap    nxt_cap Total_MC    Dal_rets    cum_rets
0   2014-02-14  702537  410011811   80883283    61942277    553539908   NaN NaN
1   2014-02-15  1054625 413848776   73684156    59127182    547714739   -1.052349   -1.052349
2   2014-02-17  1882753 407014106   70512004    59753481    539162344   -1.561469   -1.561469
3   2014-02-18  3766068 398556278   69890414    60219880    532432640   -1.248178   -1.248178
```

`merged['cum_rets'].shift(1)` should retrieve the previous value for `cum_rets` and then add it to the current value of `Dal_ret` thus incrementally sumating all values in Dal_rets. I know I could use the `.cumprod()` but i'd like to learn why my method doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> merged['cum_rets'].shift(1) should retrieve the previous value for cum_rets and then add it to the current value of Dal_ret

is correct. However, the conclusion

> thus incrementally sumating all values in Dal_rets

is not.

The expression

```
 a = b + c
```

treats `a`, `b`, and `c` as distinct arrays in the sense that it *first* adds `b` and `c`, then assigns the results to `a`. It doesn't matter if `a` and `b` refer to the same thing.

---

Incidentally, you probably want here `cumsum`, not `cumprod`.

Comment: cumsum worked great, thanks. However I still don't understand why my function just returns the value in `Dal_rets` and I would like to know why. How could I edit my code to achieve the result that cumsum produces?

Comment: It seems using `merged['cum_rets'] = merged['cum_rets'].shift(1) + merged.Dal_rets` is the same as `merged['cum_rets'] = merged.Dal_rets`. Why does adding in `merged['cum_rets'].shift(1)` not add the previous cell in cum_rets ?

Comment: @DavidHancock It doesn't make much sense to me. That would happen if `merged[`cum_rets]` were 0, and even then it would be wrong for one of the rows. I suggest you open a separate question on that, using a small example. I'm sure someone will answer, but, if you like, ping here a response and I'll be happy to have a look.